# Find() only showing first array in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

I'm having a trouble with my Redux/React project in which I call an API and look for a specific ID based on what is in a useParams. I believe I've limited the problem down to my return statement `return data.hero.find(hero => <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero} />)`

I'm not sure if that is how I should be writing it.

edit: 
I have seemed to fix the issue of the objects not being valid, however now my find() function only shows the first hero in the array, unsure of how to fix that problem without creating a new thread
HeroPage

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

import { fetchHero } from '../actions/heroAction'
import { Hero } from '../components/Hero'
import {useParams} from "react-router";

const HeroPage = () => {
    const data = useSelector(state => state.hero);
    const {heroId} = useParams()
    useEffect(() => {
        (fetchHero({heroId}))
    }, [heroId])


    let content;

    if (data.loading) content = <p>Loading posts...</p>;
    else if (data.hasErrors) content = <p>Unable to display posts</p>
    else {
        // Fill in actual check here
        const hero = data.hero.find(hero => hero.id === +heroId ? null : 'Could not find')
        // May not exist in the array
        if (hero) {
            content = <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero}/>
        }
    }


    return (
        <section>
            <h1>Hero</h1>
            {content}
        </section>
    )

}
```

Comment: If you want to render a list of Hero, you should use .map(). Try this: data.hero.map(hero => <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero} />)

Comment: I don't want to render a full list, I want to find the 'id' of the hero that I've clicked on. I already map it and after I map it I click on one of them to go to one of their own independent pages using react-router. Here I'm trying to display data from one of the hero's that i've clicked on

Comment: Have you fetch 1 hero data successfully and set its data to state? what is the type of  data.hero? Why do you use find() to render Hero component?

Comment: Yes. I've been able to fetch the entire data set, but I haven't been able to get just 1 hero from the data. data.hero I'm assuming is an object because I'm using find() to look through it to find the heroId using useParams. I don't know another way of doing this.

Comment: I think it's wrong: const heroId = useParams(), it should be: const {heroId} = useParams(), and you should test fetchHero with heroId again.

Comment: @michael I changed that and retested it. It didn't give any errors, but still with the same result of nothing showing

Comment: I think you should retest fetchHero api independently with a tool like Postman. If you will not receive the data, the API can cause error. If you receive the data, you should check whether data is stored in your state correctly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find only takes a Boolean function; don't try to do rendering in it. You should use find to get a hero, then do rendering after:

```
const hero = data.hero.find(hero => hero.id === +heroId)
if (hero) {
  content = <Hero key={hero.id} hero={hero} />
}
```

Comment: The actual answer. I danced around this the whole night. Thank you so much